# How can I download from each group of links each time one file at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing

This is the code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < imagesSatelliteUrls.Count; x++)
{
    if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[x].StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        imagesSatelliteUrls[x] = stringForSatelliteMapUrls + imagesSatelliteUrls[x];
    }

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[x].Contains("href"))
        {
            client.DownloadFile(imagesSatelliteUrls[x],
                                UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + counter.ToString("D6"));
        }
    }

    counter++;
}
```

It will download file by file . The List imagesSatelliteUrls contain 260 links of files sorted by groups.

For example:

```
index[0] "Group 1"
index[1] some link ....
index[2] some link ....
.
.
.
index[34] "Group 2"
index[35] some link ....
index[36] some link ....
.
.
.
.
index[71] "Group 3"
```

And so on there are 7 Groups.
I want it to download from each Group the first file togeather thats mean to download parallel 7 files. The first file from Group 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Then if one of the files finished in any group it will to start to download the next file from this group.

So i will see each second 7 files downloading and each file from another group.
A file is finished download in some group it should move to next one in the same group and start download it.

How can i do it ? Since this client.DownloadFile im using now just will download file by file .

Tried to download parallel:

This is the code:

```
Parallel.For(0, imagesSatelliteUrls.Count, /*new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },*/ x =>
            {
                if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[x].StartsWith("http://"))
                {
                    imagesSatelliteUrls[x] = stringForSatelliteMapUrls + imagesSatelliteUrls[x];
                }

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[x].Contains("href"))
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(imagesSatelliteUrls[x],
                                            UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + counter.ToString("D6"));
                    }
                }

                counter++;
            }); // end of Paralle
```

The exception is:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at WeatherMaps.ExtractImages.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0(Int32 x) in d:\C-Sharp\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\ExtractImages.cs:line 145
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       HResult=-2147024864
       Message=The process cannot access the file 'd:\localpath\Urls\SatelliteImage000000' because it is being used by another process.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       InnerException:
```

I also tried this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Here you can easily implement your checking algo as you see fit
                    while (counter < imagesSatelliteUrls.Count)
                    {
                        if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[count].StartsWith("http://"))
                        {
                            imagesSatelliteUrls[count] = stringForSatelliteMapUrls + imagesSatelliteUrls[count];
                        }
                        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                        {
                            if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[count].Contains("href"))
                            {

                                client.DownloadFile(imagesSatelliteUrls[count], UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + counter.ToString("D6"));
                            }
                        }

                        lock (this)
                        {
                            count++;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at WeatherMaps.ExtractImages.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__2() in d:\C-Sharp\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\ExtractImages.cs:line 122
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       HResult=-2147024864
       Message=The process cannot access the file 'd:\localpath\Urls\SatelliteImage000000' because it is being used by another process.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: if you'r targeting .Net 4.0 or higher have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Otherwise, you may want to take a look at threads on C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parallel.For

```
//for (int x = 0; x < imagesSatelliteUrls.Count; x++)
Parallel.For(0, imagesSatelliteUrls.Count, /*new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },*/ x =>
{
    if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[x].StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        imagesSatelliteUrls[x] = stringForSatelliteMapUrls + imagesSatelliteUrls[x];
    }

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[x].Contains("href"))
        {
            client.DownloadFile(imagesSatelliteUrls[x],
                                UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + x.ToString("D6"));
        }
    }

    counter++;
}); // end of Parallel.For
```

Comment: Tony tried your code and i used a breakpoint on the Client.DownloadFile line and im getting this exception after its downloading 6-7 times. Adding the exception message to my question !

Answer (score 0):

I created a standalone example of how you can do this if you add a reference to `System.Net.Http.dll` and use the `HttpClient` class.

```
// Create a mock list of data
string someImageUrl = "..."; // some test url of an image file
string urlsDirectory = @"C:\Temp"; // some working directory

var urls = new string[7 * 20];

for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i += 7)
{
    urls[i] = String.Format("Group {0}", (i / 7) + 1);

    for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
    {
        urls[i + j] = someImageUrl;
    }
}


// Download 6 files at a time.
var client = new HttpClient();

for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i += 7)
{
    var directoryPath = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(urlsDirectory, urls[i])).FullName;

    var tasks = urls.Skip(i + 1).Take(6).Select(url =>
    {
        return client.GetAsync(url);
    }).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    for (int j = 0; j < tasks.Length; j++)
    {
        var response = tasks[j].Result;

        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directoryPath, String.Format("Image {0}.jpg", j + 1)), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                responseStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing to note is that I think you lose some of WebClient's automatic filename negotiation.  It is worth doing, but you can see in my example I just labelled the images "Image 1.jpg", "Image 2.jpg", etc.

Technically when requesting files over HTTP you could request an image with a URL like the following:

```
http://somehost.com/getImage?id=5
```

In this case it's hard to say what the file name should even be.  The HTTP standard way of handling this is to add a header named `Content-Disposition` which tells the HTTP client what the name of the file should be.

But not *every* web server will give you a Content-Disposition header, so you need to fallback to trying to parse the above URL to a Windows-compatible filename.  You could try finding a simple function to strip the URL of all non-NTFS compatible characters.  But keep in mind in this case you will not get an extension (jpg, gif, etc.).  The server will probably give you a `Content-Type` header to tell you the MIME type such as "image/jpeg" but it's up to you to figure out which extension to give it.